# django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: docker, postgresql, python, django, docker-compose

I found a Django project and failed to get it running in Docker container in the following way:

1. `git clone https://github.com/hotdogee/django-blast.git`
2. `$ cat requirements.txt` in this files the below dependencies had to be updated:

   - kombu==3.0.30
   - psycopg2==2.8.6

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

For `docker-compose.yml` I use:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  dbi5k:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/dbi5k:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=django_i5k
      - POSTGRES_USER=django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres


  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
```

I had to change:

```
$ vim i5k/settings_prod.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'postgres',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

and

```
$ vim i5k/settings.py
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django_i5k',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'dbi5k',
        'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I got this error:

```
web_1    | Performing system checks...
web_1    | 
web_1    | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1    | Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f80449f4850>
web_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 223, in wrapper
web_1    |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
web_1    |     self.check_migrations()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 164, in check_migrations
web_1    |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
web_1    |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
web_1    |     self.build_graph()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 180, in build_graph
web_1    |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
web_1    |     self.ensure_schema()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
web_1    |     if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
web_1    |     cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
web_1    |     self.ensure_connection()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
web_1    |     self.connect()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
web_1    |     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
web_1    |     self.connect()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
web_1    |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 172, in get_new_connection
web_1    |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
web_1    |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1    | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1    |  Is the server running on host "dbi5k" (192.168.32.3) and accepting
web_1    |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

How is it possible to fix it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the last issue with the db host, the github generic version doesn't specify any password: [here](https://github.com/hotdogee/django-blast/blob/master/i5k/settings.py#L55) and [here](https://github.com/hotdogee/django-blast/blob/master/i5k/settings_prod.py#L23)

Comment: Thank you, I updated the linked files and docker-compose.yml in my question. Unfortunately, I ran into `web_1    | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1    |  Is the server running on host "dbi5k" (192.168.32.3) and accepting
web_1    |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`. What did I miss?

Comment: I am not sure I agree with the approach to replace one question with another when the initial one is solved. Instead it is better to rate the answer (if helpful) and create a separate post/questions with a new problem. This way we have a record of both questions where other users can benefit from reading them and applying to their situations.
As for your question. Did you make sure the containers are running?